# Uploading a file to AWS S3 from client using a presigned url. How can I find out when the file has finished uploading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file from the client (react app) directly to s3 using a presigned url like this:

```js
// Tell the server to request a presigned url I can use to upload the file
const { data } = await client.query({
  query: UPLOAD_URL,
  variables: { filename: file.name, filetype: file.type},
})
// Use the presigned url to upload the file to s3
axios.put(data.uploadUrl.url, file, { headers: { 'Content-Type': file.type } })
```

How can I find out that the upload has finished?

Comment: axios.put(data.uploadUrl.url, file, { headers: { 'Content-Type': file.type } }).then(() => {
// this code will execute when upload finished
})

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to await for the response from `axios.put`.

```js
  async function uploadFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0]
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: UPLOAD_URL,
      variables: { filename: file.name, filetype: file.type},
    })

    const res = await axios.put(data.uploadUrl.url, file, { headers: { 'Content-Type': file.type } })
    console.log('finished uploading')
    setImages((prev) => [...prev, data.uploadUrl.filepath])
  }
```